# Is there any way to check if bubble triggered the click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Clicking on elements in jQuery causes bubble up to body. If we have a click handler binded to body that shows an alert, then clicking on any element will bubble up to body and trigger the alert. My Question is, is there any way to know if the body alert was triggered as a result of direct click to body, or was the click triggered because of a bubble up to body.

Comment: Whatever you do, be wary of stopPropagation. That will break all `.live` calls.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Compare [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target) to `this`. `this` is always the event where the handler is bound; `event.target` is always the element where the event originated.

```
$(document.body).click(function(event) {
    if (event.target == this) {
        // event was triggered on the body
    }
});
```

In the case of elements you know to be unique in a document (basically, just `body`) you can also check the `nodeName` of `this`:

```
$(document.body).click(function(event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'body') {
        // event was triggered on the body
    }
});
```

You have to do `toLowerCase()` because the case of `nodeName` is inconsistent across browsers.

One last option is to compare to an ID if your element has one, because these also have to be unique:

```
$('#foo').click(function(event) {
    if (event.target.id === 'foo') {
        // event was triggered on #foo
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can check what was clicked with [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/):

```
$(something).click(function(e){
    alert(e.target)
})
```

Answer (score 5):

In React, we can directly get using currentTarget and target

```
import React from "react";

function Bar() {
    return (
            <div
               onClick={(ev) => {
                  if (ev.target == ev.currentTarget) console.log("Target hit");
                }}
             >
              Click me, maybe <div>test doesnt trigger hit</div>
            </div>
     );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The "event" parameter passed to the handler has a "target" property, which refers to the element that was the direct target of the event. You can check that property to see if it's the `<body>` element.

Note that the jQuery ".delegate()" facility can be used to do that checking for you.

Answer (score 1):

In React, you need to create a reference to the Component with React.createRef(). Something like this:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.eRef = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div
        ref={this.eRef}
        onClick={(ev) => {
          if (ev.target == this.eRef.current) console.log("Target hit");
        }}
      >
        Click me, maybe
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```